# OWASP ZAP Pitchfork?

Tags: owasp, zap, fuzzer

I am doing the Broken brute-force protection, IP block lab
Have been trying to figure out a way to make a script that does the pitchfork attack by using the fuzzer http sender js template but I have no idea how to.

tried using [ZAP missing payload mode pitchfork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603013/zap-missing-payload-mode-pitchfork)
[OWASP ZAP fuzzer header and body]
([OWASP ZAP fuzzer header and body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100470/owasp-zap-fuzzer-header-and-body))
but it has 2 payloads and from a file I selected from payload tab after you select it and use it on the highlighted words

how would you make the script and other question how would you do in 2 places
like example
username: calos
password: 123456

[screenshot of zap][the password and usernames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bxjn.png)(https://www.stackoverflow.com/)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDkl5.png)

Comment: I believe this answer covers the lab you're talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72112186/7718222

Comment: One is set by the fuzzer one is set by the script. (Yes we know that's sub-optimal, fuzzer changes are on the way ). This is just a "works for now" kinda thing, until we can get those done (which is difficult with a small team).